# Positive reach..

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth closed $d$-manifold embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $d_M: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $d_M(x) = \min_{m\in M} d(x,m)$.

Define $M\oplus \epsilon = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n \mid d_M(x) \leq \epsilon\}$. The reach of $M$, ${\rm Reach}(M)$, is the largest $\epsilon$ such that any element of $M\oplus \epsilon$ has a unique nearest point in $M$.

I have seen the assumption ${\rm Reach}(M) > 0$ quite a few places. Can someone provide me with a non-trivial example for which ${\rm Reach}(M) = 0$? Thanks!

Comment: Not for smoothly embedded closed manifolds. You need a non-compact manifold or a non-smooth embedding for that.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, you could use a triangle or something similar. But now I'm confused about the condiitions in the paper!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is being non-compact. For example
$$M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} | xy = \pm 1\}$$
has reach 0 because $M$ approaches the $x$-axis which has no unique nearest point.